# how to insert multiple Arrays to RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 Arrays

```
ArrayList<String> jawabansiswa;
ArrayList<String> jawabanbenar;
ArrayList<String> txtsoal;
```

I want to show this all to Recycler View

In my code I used this for adapter and logcat show there exception

```
    public arrayadapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> jawabansiswa, ArrayList<String> jawabanbenar, ArrayList<String> txtsoal) {
        this.c = c;
        this.jawabansiswa = jawabansiswa;
        this.jawabanbenar = jawabanbenar;
        this.txtsoal = txtsoal;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull arrayadapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.jawabansiswa.setText(jawabansiswa.get(position));
        holder.jawabanbenarx.setText(jawabanbenar.get(position));
        holder.txtsoalx.setText(txtsoal.get(position));
    }
```

Its my logcat exception

```
 Process: com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif, PID: 28187
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif.arrayadapter.onBindViewHolder(arrayadapter.java:41)
        at com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif.arrayadapter.onBindViewHolder(arrayadapter.java:15)
```

Can I get source code to show 3 Arraylists in one Recyclerview like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6hE9.png)

Comment: Either use 3 recycler views, or use 1 with all items being a part of a single array, with 3 different view types (if they're different)

Comment: better you can try collection of array list using setter and getter classes , if the data was empty you can set empty string then above issue can resolve easily

Comment: @PoovarasanSelvaraj do you have code to use collection of Arrays using setter or getter class, i can't found it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(position<=jawabansiswa.size()-1){
holder.jawabansiswa.setText(jawabansiswa.get(position));
}

if(position<=jawabanbenar.size()-1){
holder.jawabanbenarx.setText(jawabanbenar.get(position));
}

 if(position<=txtsoal.size()-1){
 holder.txtsoalx.setText(txtsoal.get(position));
}
```

Comment: this work, but not show all my array,that phone problem or something else?

Comment: U need to make sure that the array has all the values as u expected

Comment: yes, all of my arrays have 4 values, i check it to in log.d , maybe use setter and getter better than use 3 arrays directly to recyclerview ?

Comment: cause i try again,sometimes it work, sometimes it just show 2 arrays

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems your Arrays length are unequal thats why it is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException. Please make sure your array lengths are equal. One thing you can do to handel this exeption is checking length of individual array list before directly setting it to textView. Modify your code like this:-

```
 holder.jawabansiswa.setText((jawabansiswa.size()-1)>position?"":jawabansiswa.get(position));
 holder.jawabanbenarx.setText((jawabanbenar.size()-1)>position?"":jawabanbenar.get(position));
 holder.txtsoalx.setText((txtsoal.size()-1)>position?"":txtsoal.get(position));
```

what I have done is that I have checked the size of individual arraylist and applied if else in that. If the position index of recycler view doesn't exits in list then set text as empty

Comment: this still not work, is there another method to use 3 arraylist in recyclerview?